# iTunes Match and iOS device storage

Tags: ipad, ios, music, itunes-match

When I enabled iTunes Match (which is generally *brilliant*), it wiped my iPhone's music library as I expected it to, but it didn't wipe my iPad library.

Now that I've got iTunes Match working so nicely, I want to reclaim the space from the music I was carrying around in case I wanted it. But I can't find a way to bulk-delete music either on the device or from iTunes. Now that it's Match-managed, iTunes shows my music listing greyed out and uneditable. On the iPad I can delete songs one by one, but that's not what I want.

How can I wipe clean an iTunes Match-driven music library on an iOS device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings>General>Usage>
Wait for the storage amounts to load then click on Music and swipe left or right.  It will delete all the music on the iDevise in on fell swoop.

Comment: Yes it does! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do it on the device, but you should be able to do it in iTunes by turning off music syncing.